# What are some processor monitoring tools for Ubuntu

Tags: cpu, monitoring, temperature

What are some good tools that I could use to monitor my processor? I know of some tools like SpeedFan and CoreTemp for Windows, but I need a Linux alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for real-time monitoring on-screen or logging?

There are many tools that monitor these readings and log & graph them. I use [collectd](http://collectd.org/) with a hacked version of [rrd.cgi](http://haroon.sis.utoronto.ca/rrd/scripts/) for drawing the graphs.

For on-screen displays and other tools, search for "temp" in the package repositories ([like so](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=temp&searchon=names&suite=maverick&section=all)) will give you some options to chose from for monitoring temperatures, and there is a simple system monitor that shows you CPU use, memory use, and network IO.